# Rails will_paginate directs to wrong twitter bootstrap nav-tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, will-paginate, bootstrap-tabs

I have a nav-tab (twitter-bootstrap) in my homepage with 2 tabs.
Under each tab I render a different collection:

home_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @deleted_posts = Post.all.where(status: "deleted").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  @edited_posts = Post.all.where(status: "edited").paginate(page: params[:pr_page], per_page: 5)
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div class="tabbable"> 
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href=<%="#tabDeleted"%> data-toggle="tab"><%= t "deleted" %></a></li>
    <li><a href=<%= "#tabEdited" %> data-toggle="tab"><%= "edited" %></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id=<%="tabDeleted" %>>
      <%= render @deleted_posts %>
      <%= will_paginate @deleted_posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id=<%="tabEdited" %>>
      <%= render @edited_posts %>
      <%= will_paginate @edited_posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, :param_name => "pr_page" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The pagination works fine within the first tab (deleted_posts).

When I switch to the second tab (edited_posts) the first page is shown correctly, although my url still shows the page params of the first tab:

```
 http://localhost:3000/home/index?page=3
```

and when I try to go to another page it directs me to the first page of the first tab (deleted_posts) and the page param is just being added to the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/home/index?page=3&pr_page=2
```

How do I fix it? 
And maybe this is actually the question: Since Twitter Bootstrap nav-tabs don't add params to the url, how can my app know in which tab the user is?
And how to I delete the page params from the wrong tab to the url (because as is, it adds both tabs' page params to the url)?

Answer (score 2):

Specify `:param_name` on both calls to `will_paginate` function. Specifying `:param_name` on  only one call is making it add the default `:page` param to both paginations.

Eg:

```
  <%= will_paginate @deleted_posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, :param_name => "deleted_posts" %>

  <%= will_paginate @edited_posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, :param_name => "edited_posts" %>
```

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't make any difference. Still both are added.